# Is it possible to have multiple default mysql servers in phpMyAdmin using docker

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to build enviroment using Docker with two MySQL servers, and one phpMyAdmin server to easily analyze data during development.
My docker-compose.yml looks like this.

```
version: "3.9"
  services:
    database1:
      container_name: Database1
      image: mysql:8.0.28
      command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
      restart: always
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: database1
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somepassword
        MYSQL_USER: databaseuser1
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: databaseuser1
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      volumes:
        - database-volume:/var/lib/mysql
      networks: 
        - my_network
      database2:
      container_name: Database2
      image: mysql:8.0.28
      command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
      restart: always
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: database2
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somepassword
        MYSQL_USER: databaseuser2
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: databaseuser2
      ports:
        - "3307:3306"
      volumes:
        - second-database-volume:/var/lib/mysql
      networks: 
        - my_network      
    phpmyadmin:
      container_name: PhpMyAdmin
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5.1.3
      restart: always
      depends_on:
        - database1
        - database2
      environment:
        PMA_HOST: database1, database2
        PMA_PORT: 3306, 3307
        PMA_USER: databaseuser1, databaseuser2
        PMA_PASSWORD: databaseuser1, databaseuser2
      ports:
        - "8080:80"
      networks: 
        - my_network
volumes:
  database-volume:
  second-database-volume:

networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
```

I was wondering is there any build in way to archive this.

Answer (score 2):

Did you been tried to change the environment variable `PMA_HOST` to `PMA_HOSTS`?

[image: Screenshot of phpMyAdmin select server]

[Official phpMyAdmin Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes!!! You can connect multiple DB with a single PhpMyAdmin instance in docker.

Please find a sample here:

```
version: "3"
networks:
  sample_network:
services:
  db-1:
    image: mariadb:10.5.8
    container_name: db-1
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: notSecureWay
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db-1
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: notSecureWay
    networks:
      - sample_network
#    ports:
#      - 8087:3306
    volumes:
      - db1_data:/var/lib/mysql

  db-2:
    image: mariadb:10.5.8
    container_name: db-2
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: notSecureWay
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db-2
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: notSecureWay
    networks:
      - sample_network
#    ports:
#      - 8088:3306
    volumes:
      - db2_data:/var/lib/mysql
      
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    links:
      - db-1
      - db2
    environment:
      PMA_HOSTS: dv-1,db-2
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    networks:
      - sample_network
    ports:
      - 8090:80


volumes:
  db1_data:
  db2_data:
```

Start your phpMyAdmin app in browser using http://localhost:8090/
You can select the database in the login screen of your phpMyAdmin app.

Answer (score 0):

Besides `PMA_HOSTS` also [customized configuration](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html?highlight=PMA_USER_CONFIG_BASE64#customizing-configuration) can be used. Create a file called `config.user.inc.php` and put the content below.

```
<?php

#config.user.inc.php file

$cfg['Servers'] = [
    1 => [ #For MySQL instance inside docker compose
        'auth_type' => 'config',
        'host' => 'container_name',
        'user' => 'USER',
        'password' => 'PASSWORD',
    ],
    2 => [ # for remote connection
        'auth_type' => 'config',
        'host' => 'REMOTE_HOST_IP',
        'user' => 'USER',
        'password' => 'PASSWORD'
    ],
    # Add other connections if needed.
];
```

Then, add a new volume `localPath/config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php`

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [phpMyAdmin documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html?highlight=docker), there are environment variables to do this.

There is **PMA_HOSTS** to setup phpMyAdmin container with a list of servers available in a dropdown.
Remove **PMA_HOST** and replace with **PMA_HOSTS** with a comma separated list of hosts.

If all your hosts use the same port, you can keep **PMA_PORT**.
But if you have multiple ports then replace **PMA_PORT** with **PMA_PORTS** so you can provide a comma separated list of ports.